# Getting response from API using Alamofire

Tags: swift, uitableview, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to get response from API to load data into tableviews however my alamofire functions works but only in some view controllers I dont understand what Im doing wrong. And i know its the alamofire function because i have used debuggers to follow my data and code but I saw the problem where the function never goes ahead of the first line of function.

**Alamofire Function**

```
Alamofire.request("\(baseURL)").responseJSON { response in
            if let dict = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] {
                for obj in dict {
                    let latest = LatestNews(getLatest: obj)
                    self.moreNews.append(latest)
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

**Array and Model Class**

```
 var latestNews: LatestNews!

 var moreNews = [LatestNews]()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are having.."it works in some view controllers, but not in others", is the result of the fact that you are reloading your tableView on a background thread.  You have to move it to the Main thread like so:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.tableView.reloadData()   
    }
```